# Why can not I import 'androidx.core.app.NotificationChannelCompat'?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library, androidx

I am using `androidx.core.app.NotificationChannel` and `androidx.core.app.NotificationChannelCompat` to resovle the android compatible problem according to (Androidx API reference)[https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationChannelCompat].

But even I add `implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.1` in my build.gradle file, Android Studio prompts me can not resovle symbole `NotificationChannelCompat`.

Why? I do not want use SDK version conditional statements to fill my source code.

Comment: Try to "Clean the Build" thereafter "Refresh Gradle Project".

Comment: @FelixFavourChinemerem thank you for you comment. But I can not find the "clean the build" menu item. I just found "invalidate cache/restart ...", but it has no help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your PC?

Comment: @FelixFavourChinemerem Would you please start an empty project to verify it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll resolve `NotificationChannelCompat` if you change:

```
 implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.2"
```

to

```
 implementation "androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha04"
```

Latest versions: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

Here is the commit, it was missing :-) https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1360061